# Self-signed certificate chain verified by OpenSSL but Windows says leaf is invalid

Tags: certificates, windows, certificate-authority, openssl

Let's say I have `rootCA.crt`, `intermediateCA.crt` and `leaf.crt`. I used `openssl` to veriy `leaf.crt`:

```
cat rootCA.crt intermediate.crt > chain.crt
openssl verify -CAfile chain.crt leaf.crt
```

and it said everything was OK.

I later added `rootCA.crt` as `Trusted Root` and `intermediateCA.crt` as `Intermediate Root`. Opening either of them in Windows shows that they are trusted, for `intermedaiteCA.crt` it even shows `rootCA.crt` as parent. But when I open `leaf.crt` it says that `This certificate has an invalid digital signature.` I tried to add it to certificate store using `Automatically select the certificate store based on type of certificate`, but even then it is still not trusted and Windows claims that it has invalid signature.

`leaf.crt` is issued for our local `gitlab` instance (but not as cert for `https`, it has `Key Usage = Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (b0)`). The only thing I can think of is that its `CN` is not in `SAN` field. It has `CN = zs.node.broker-GITLAB` while `SAN` contains `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, machine's IP and DNS name `gitlab.our-local-domain`. `CN` is the way it is because we issue certificates for various devices and it was decided that this server will use one of these certificates. Unfortunately I cannot create ad-hoc certificate to check it and that is why I'd like to verify as much as I can before starting painful process of issuing another certificate.

Except for that (`CN` not in `SAN` for `leaf.crt`) all certificates are pretty standard I think. They are all 2048 bit, signature algorithm is `sha256RSA`.
`rootCA` has `Key Usage = Certificate Signing, Off-line CRL Signing, CRL Signing (06)`, `Basic Constraints = (Subject Type=CA, Path Length Constraint=None)`. (Both with little yellow triangle with exclamation mark in Windows certificate display - I don't know why really).
`intermediateCA` has `Key Usage = Certificate Signing, Off-line CRL Signing, CRL Signing (06)`, `Basic Constraints = (Subject Type=CA, Path Length Constraint=0)`.

Do I have some serious issues with my certificates or is it something simple?

Comment: The little yellow triangle with exclamation mark (sounds like it should be a Unicode character, but isn't) indicates extension marked critical; BC always is, and KU (if present) usually is. Are you asserting your leaf KU _prevents_ https (or other TLS) -- it doesn't -- or just that you don't use this cert for https/TLS? That said, `openssl verify` by default doesn't check self-signature on root while Windows does, but that doesn't explain a difference on leaf. You might try adding `-x509_strict` and see if it catches anything, although I think signature check shouldn't need it.

Comment: I'm just stating that I'm not using this certificate for https. They are used for TLS (which I *think* is less strict than https, AFAIR TLS does not verify CN/SAN but there is a high chance I am wrong) - I don't know if they include all proper Key usages for this - but this is outside of my current problem. Running `openssl verify -x509_strict -CAfile chain.crt leaf.crt` passes without any issues.

Comment: TLS is used for many things, _some_ of which (including https) check hostname and some of which don't. See rfc 6125 for some important cases, but it's not exhaustive. If -x509_strict doesn't catch anything I'm mystified -- unless you can post actual certs for people (including me) to try, and you would probably need to generate a nonsensitive test cert for that which conflicts with your goal of not generating a cert :-(